# Not able to move quad wheel robot

Tags: unity

I am trying to move QWAD wheel robot, I have grouped the wheels separately and added wheels colliders for each wheel.
The problem is that the wheels are moving but the robot is stationary. I have been stuck with this problem from many days.
I am very new to unity3D and C# scripting. At first I tried the concept of moving rigid body using car model and it is working perfectly fine. When I applied the same logic to QWAD wheel ROBOT is not woking as expeted, kindly help me out.

Please find the code below

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class RoboMovemnt : MonoBehaviour
{
void Start()
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
}
public void GetInput()
{
    m_horizontalInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    m_verticalInput = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");        


}
private void Steer()
{
    m_steeringAngle = maxSteerAngle * m_horizontalInput;
    FR_Wheelwc.steerAngle = m_steeringAngle;
    FL_Wheelwc.steerAngle = m_steeringAngle;
}
private void Accelerate()
{
    RR_Wheelwc.motorTorque = m_verticalInput*motorForce;
    RL_Wheelwc.motorTorque = m_verticalInput * motorForce;

    if (m_verticalInput == 0)
    {
        RL_Wheelwc.brakeTorque = brakeTorque;
        RR_Wheelwc.brakeTorque = brakeTorque;
    }

}

private void UpdateWheelPoses()
{
    UpdateWheelPose(FR_Wheelwc, FR_WheelT);
    UpdateWheelPose(FL_Wheelwc, FL_WheelT);
    UpdateWheelPose(RR_Wheelwc, RR_WheelT);
    UpdateWheelPose(RL_Wheelwc, RL_WheelT);

}
private void UpdateWheelPose(WheelCollider _collider ,Transform _transform)
{
    Vector3 _pos = _transform.position;
    Quaternion _quat = _transform.rotation;

    _collider.GetWorldPose(out _pos, out _quat);

    _transform.position = _pos;
    _transform.rotation = _quat;

}
void HandBrake()
{
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        IsBrake = true;
    }
    else
    {
        IsBrake = false;
    }
    if(IsBrake == true)
    {
        RL_Wheelwc.brakeTorque = brakeTorque;
        RR_Wheelwc.brakeTorque = brakeTorque;

        RL_Wheelwc.motorTorque = 0;
        RR_Wheelwc.motorTorque = 0;

    }
    else
    {
        RL_Wheelwc.brakeTorque = 0;
        RR_Wheelwc.brakeTorque = 0;

    }
}


private void FixedUpdate()
{
    GetInput();
    Steer();
    Accelerate();
    UpdateWheelPoses();
    HandBrake();   

}


private float m_horizontalInput;
private float m_verticalInput;
private float m_steeringAngle;
private Rigidbody rb;
private int Velocity;

public WheelCollider FR_Wheelwc, FL_Wheelwc, RR_Wheelwc, RL_Wheelwc;
public Transform  FR_WheelT, FL_WheelT, RR_WheelT, RL_WheelT;
public float maxSteerAngle = 30;
public float motorForce  = 500;
public bool IsBrake = false;
public float brakeTorque = 50000f;

}
```

Comment: Moving a physics object by setting its transform position/rotation directly is generally not what you want to do. Can you explain what Update Wheel Pose is intended to do?

Comment: @DMGregory: Thanks for the response,when I am trying to move the ROBOT collider of wheels are roatating ,to get the position of the wheel collider I am using UpdateWheelPose()  and to update the position of the wheel internally I am using GetWorldPose API.Kindly suggest me if there are any other methods to move the ROBOT.